# A RVM version () is installed yet 1.25.14 (master) is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bash

I was trying to install ruby using Homebrew and RVM and after I installed RVM terminal (was about to start installing ruby 2.0.0) accidentally quit and when I reopened it I had the error:

```
A RVM version  () is installed yet 1.25.14 (master) is loaded.
Please do one of the following:
  * 'rvm reload'
  * open a new shell
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=1 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for auto reload with msg.
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for silent auto reload.
```

and when I try `rvm reload` I get:

```
-bash: cat: No such file or directory
ERROR: Missing proper 'which' command. Make sure it is installed before using RVM!

[Process completed]
```

To make this situation even worse when I try most commands i get that same error:

```
" -bash: command: No such file or directory "
```

also my permissions to view my `.bash_profile` are denied. 
I'm using `OSX 10.9.1`

thanks.

Comment: HOW were you trying to install RVM? What instructions? The only instructions I recommend are provided by the authors of RVM, who know it better than anyone. Read through [the installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) completely so you understand your options, before trying to install it. RVM is useful but it's powerful too, and with power comes some complexity so know your options. Also, you might try asking this on the RVM channel on freenode.

Comment: why your permissions to view my **.bash_profile** are denied? Did you install rvm and setup bash from yourself?

Comment: I was using http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion for instructions. I fixed it by reinstalling mac ox x 10.9. I'm not sure why my permissions to .bash_profile were denied but I was able to change them after reinstalling os x and unhiding the file. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo rm -rf /users/your_username/.rvm
```

Then close and reopen the terminal.

There should also be a disk repair utility for MacOS that repairs file permissions too (something in /Applications/Utilities)

On that note, make sure you don't have MacPorts installed as well.